# "fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found" using clang on Apple M1

Tags: macos, clang, openmp, eigen, apple-m1

Clang isn't able to find `omp.h` whenever I try to compile with openMP flag. Here's what I'm trying to do

```
clang++ -dynamiclib -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.3.9/include/eigen3/ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -o libfoo.dylib foolibrary.cpp -lomp
```

Although I have omp.h in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/11.0.1/include/omp.h`, while clang is in `usr/bin/clang`. Is there anything I need to configure so that it's able to find it?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990296/how-to-include-omp-h-in-os-x ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the OP is using the wrong compiler. I've already tried using apple's clang and also llvm clang that comes when you use `brew instal llvm` and both give the same error.

Comment: How about installing gcc and using it?

Comment: My team used to build the library with gcc but they moved to building it with clang, since building with gcc gave them problems later on when using the library. The problem is that I'm the only one using an M1 mac while they use an intel one and it seems to be harder to set up openMP with clang under arm64 architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using brew to target the M1 natively, the brew installed clang is *not* in `/usr/bin`.
The [brew instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) show that the preferred location for it is `/opt/homebrew`. The clang in /usr/bin is a link to the Apple command line tools one; you can see that by using `-v`.

```
$ /usr/bin/clang -v
/usr/bin/clang -v
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

To get the brew installed clang you need to follow the instructions brew gave you when you installed it :-

```
llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```

Doing that resolves the include issue, but, at least for me, not the library linking one.

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang -v -fopenmp hello_omp.c
clang version 11.1.0
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
 "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/bin/clang-11" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx11.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Werror=undef-prefix -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello_omp.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-rounding-math -munwind-tables -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -target-cpu apple-a7 -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 609.8 -v -resource-dir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/lib/clang/11.1.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/lib/clang/11.1.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/jcownie/tmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=163 -fopenmp -fopenmp-cuda-parallel-target-regions -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fmax-type-align=16 -o /var/folders/lt/nf3dtk8j16qfsl97d_vgv4dw000lts/T/hello_omp-bd4ce3.o -x c hello_omp.c
clang -cc1 version 11.1.0 based upon LLVM 11.1.0 default target arm64-apple-darwin20.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/lib/clang/11.1.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 11.0.0 0.0.0 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out /var/folders/lt/nf3dtk8j16qfsl97d_vgv4dw000lts/T/hello_omp-bd4ce3.o -lomp -lSystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/lib/clang/11.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If you explicitly pass the recommended `$LDFLAGS`, then things work...

```
$ echo $LDFLAGS
-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib
$ /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang $LDFLAGS -fopenmp hello_omp.c
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang $LDFLAGS -fopenmp hello_omp.c
$ ./a.out
./a.out
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 5
Hello from thread 4
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 7
Hello from thread 6
$
```

My (hacky, but it works) solution to that has been to create my own shell scripts to invoke the compilers with the appropriate library path; you can see this hack in [How to build LLVM (clang,clang++) for Apple M1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293299/how-to-build-llvm-clang-clang-for-apple-m1)

Note that at one more point  the support for OpenMP tasks was broken in LLVM when targeting the M1. (See "[Crash in passing firstprivate args to tasks on Apple M1](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48885)"). However, that was fixed in March 2021, so be sure to use a more recent LLVM release.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal:

```
brew install libomp
```

Then in your Makefile:

```
CC=clang++
FLAGS=-g -Wall -std=c++17 -arch arm64 -lomp
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include
```

My Mac & clang:

```
clang -v
```

Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)

Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0

Thread model: posix