# Clang openMP support on Apple M1?

Tags: macos, clang, openmp, eigen, apple-m1

I've been trying to build a library that uses openMP using clang but I get this error:

```
In file included from cafxlibrary.cpp:2:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.3.9/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.3.9/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:266:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Even though I have omp.h in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/11.0.1/include/`. I've tried setting up the environment variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to point to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/11.0.1/include/` but I get this error instead:

```
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The command I'm using is:

```
clang++ -dynamiclib -DNDEBUG -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.3.9/include/eigen3/ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -o libcafx.dylib cafxlibrary.cpp -lomp -std=c++11
```

I've also tried without `-lomp`. I also have installed `llvm` and `libomp` using homebrew but the problem persists. I've also tried placing `omp.h` directly in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.3.9/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is looking for `libomp.dylib` ... instead of passing `-lomp` to the linker, try `-L/opt/homebrew/lib/libomp.dylib` or wherever the path to libomp is

Comment: Can you maybe add the output of `clang -v ...` to the post, so that we can see more of the compiler invocation that happens in the background?

Comment: This seems very close to being a duplicateof your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663120/fatal-error-omp-h-file-not-found-using-clang-on-apple-m1 which I have answered.