# Makefile(C++): unsupported option '-fopenmp'(macOS Bigsur)

Tags: c++, makefile, openmp

As in the title, I get this error, when I try to compile my program using makefile. When I run it in clion environment, everything is fine. I installed homebrew llvm library. Also I have Xcode. Here is my makefile:

```
output: main.o
    g++ main.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -fopenmp -std=c++17 -c -g -Wall -pedantic -Werror -o main.o main.cpp
```

I understand, there are similar questions related to this topic, however I was unable to solve this issue.

Comment: try passing -Xclang -fopenmp, if it doesn't work try using clang++

Comment: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found. When using -Xclang++ I have 'unsupported -fopenmp' again.

Comment: No, try compiling with `clang++ -Xclang -fopenmp -std=c++17 -c -g -Wall -pedantic -Werror -o main.o main.cpp`
I also always had problems with openmp on mac, if this doesn't work consider using CMake

Comment: Still got fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found. Unfortunately, I have to use makefile for this assignment.

Comment: @Cthuwu interesting that you got a omp.h not found when using the other setup.  perhaps you need to explicitly tell it where the header file is with a -I/location/of/header. ??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663120/fatal-error-omp-h-file-not-found-using-clang-on-apple-m1/66688630#66688630