# ERROR: Could not build wheels for bgzip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: installation, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to install Panagram https://github.com/kjenike/panagram on my Mac.

The machine is an Apple M2 Max running the Ventura 13.4 OS.

The installation fails when it tries to install bgzip - I have pasted the error messages below.

I have tried to install bgzip separately using pip install bgzip but hit the same error. I have updated pip and setuptools and that has also not helped. There seems to be a problem locating the file omp.h

Any help would be gratefully received!!!

Building wheels for collected packages: panagram, bgzip
Building wheel for panagram (pyproject.toml) ... done
Created wheel for panagram: filename=panagram-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=408400 sha256=a9e98448c1a4227d19787cdc56ac633badc626f3988329188d6d00a56049e3c8
Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/6z/dbjpst5x7hx744d90zzkd44m0000gp/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-38jvsf0r/wheels/3b/c8/bd/ebc2cce9e7698f91d56739369e5637dd397ec70adccc24b97c
Building wheel for bgzip (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [18 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/bgzip
copying bgzip/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/bgzip
copying bgzip/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/bgzip
running build_ext
building 'bgzip.bgzip_utils' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/bgzip_utils
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/irh25/mambaforge/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/irh25/mambaforge/include -arch arm64 -I/Users/irh25/mambaforge/include/python3.10 -c bgzip_utils/bgzip_utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/bgzip_utils/bgzip_utils.o -O3 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
bgzip_utils/bgzip_utils.c:615:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bgzip
Running setup.py clean for bgzip
Successfully built panagram
Failed to build bgzip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bgzip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/bgzip/

**Requirements**

bgzip requires `openmp`. On MacOS it can be installed with:

```
brew install llvm
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72569134/7976758

The answer recommends to run

```
brew install libomp
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fatal+error%3A+omp.h+file+not+found

Comment: Thanks - I installed both llvm and libomp using those commands but still get the same error.