# How compile program with openMP functions?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, clang, apple-m1

I tried to run the code related to OpenMP and parallelization on mac m1, but I ran into a number of problems.
The usual connection of the header file <omp.h> didn't work in VSC, so I installed libomp via homebrew and now have the following:
path to the header file: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/18.1.2/include/omp`
and library path:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/18.1.2/lib/libgmp.dylib`

How can I compile the final project? He always gives me an error: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 ... linker command failed with exit code 1 OR unsupported option '-fopenmp'.`

I try use `gcc -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/18.1.2/include matrix_functions.c -o main`, but it's useless.

Comment: [How to install OpenMP on Mac M1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71061894/how-to-install-openmp-on-mac-m1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install OpenMP on Mac M1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71061894/how-to-install-openmp-on-mac-m1)